# Set VM's $PATH via Puppet config.yaml or Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I would like to add an additional path to my VM's $PATH environment variable through use of my puppet `config.yaml` or `Vagrant` file (or some other VM external mechanism that I don't know).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: `PATH` is a per-shell setting so it really depends on what you want this to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vagrant you can easilly provision stuff with a [shell script](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html). So first, create a script (in the same folder than your Vagrantfile) that add additional path to `$PATH`. By exemple, create a file called `bootstrap.sh` with this content :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar
# Or if you want it for all users :
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar' >> /etc/profile
```

Then in your `Vagrantfile`, add this line to execute this script when the VM is booted :

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

Comment: It worked after I changed the `Vagrantfile` line to: `config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"`

Comment: You can also use the [inline script](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html#inline-scripts) provisioning if you want to have the all in the Vagrant file and no external `.sh` file

Answer (score 0):

This approach is partway there, but if for some reason you re-run provisioning on your Vagrant box, you'll end up with one of those lines in there for each time you run the provisioning. To avoid that:

```
grep -s -E "PATH=\$PATH:/foo/bar" /etc/profile || echo 'PATH=\$PATH:/foo/bar' >> /etc/profile
```

I don't know much about Chef, but Salt does a great job of creating a managed section in such files and then dealing with it on it's own. I'd be surprised if Chef doesn't do the same thing.